# OnActivityResult is working fine in all my and 100 above devices but not in some devices like micromax AQ4501

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I don't know why `data.getParcelableExtra("data");` returns null.

My code:

```
    public class ProfilePage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView Profile_pic;
    EditText Name, Designation, Mobile, Email, City, State, Country, Website;
    Button Save, Back;
    private int ProfileID = 0;
    DbHelper MYDB;

    private static final int RESULT = 1;
    private Menu mainMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page);
        try{
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("DS Nav:", e.getMessage());
        }

        MYDB = new DbHelper(this);

        Profile_pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePicture);
        Profile_pic.setOnClickListener(this);

        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileName);
        Designation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileDesignation);
        Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileMobile);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileEmail);
        City = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileCity);
        State = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileState);
        Country = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileCountry);
        Website = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProfileWebsite);

        Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProfileSave);
        Save.setOnClickListener(this);

        Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProfileBack);
        Back.setOnClickListener(this);


        try{
            String ProfilePicturePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DS Images/Profile_Picture.png";
            File Picfile = new File(ProfilePicturePath);
            if(Picfile.exists()){
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ProfilePicturePath);
                Profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "You can change Your Picture with Click on Profile Picture.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Please Click on Default Picture and Change Your Profile Picture with Your Original Picture.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Load data In EditText Fields if Available in Database:
        try{
            Cursor datacursor = MYDB.getData(null, null);
            if(datacursor.moveToFirst()) {
                this.ProfileID = datacursor.getInt(0);
                Name.setText(datacursor.getString(1));
                Designation.setText(datacursor.getString(2));
                Mobile.setText(datacursor.getString(3));
                Email.setText(datacursor.getString(4));
                City.setText(datacursor.getString(5));
                State.setText(datacursor.getString(6));
                Country.setText(datacursor.getString(7));
                Website.setText(datacursor.getString(8));
            }else{
                NotRegistered();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
/*
*            Uri SelectedImage = data.getData();
*            String[] filepath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
*
*            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SelectedImage, filepath, *null, null, null);
*            cursor.moveToFirst();
*
*            int Column = cursor.getColumnIndex(filepath[0]);
*            String PicPath = cursor.getString(Column);
*/

            final Bitmap b = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
            /*BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PicPath);*/

            try{
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DS Images");
                if(!file.exists()){
                    if(!file.mkdirs()){
                        Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Error: Folder Not Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Folder Successfully Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DS Images/", "Profile_Picture"
                        + ".png"));


                Boolean savePic = b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

                    if(savePic){
                        Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Picture Successfully Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Error: Picture Not Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                fos.flush();
                    fos.close();

                    String ProfilePicturePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DS Images/Profile_Picture.png";
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ProfilePicturePath);
                    Profile_pic.setImageBitmap(b);
                ExtraFunctions funcs = new ExtraFunctions(ProfilePage.this);
                funcs.refreshGallery(ProfilePage.this, new File(ProfilePicturePath));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.ivProfilePicture:

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.putExtra("crop","true");
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT);

                break;

            case R.id.btnProfileSave:

                final String ProfileName, ProfileDesignation, ProfileMobile, ProfileEmail, ProfileCity, ProfileState, ProfileCountry, ProfileWebsite;
                ProfileName = Name.getText().toString();
                ProfileDesignation = Designation.getText().toString();
                ProfileMobile = Mobile.getText().toString();
                ProfileEmail = Email.getText().toString();
                ProfileCity = City.getText().toString();
                ProfileState = State.getText().toString();
                ProfileCountry = Country.getText().toString();
                ProfileWebsite = Website.getText().toString();

                int update;

                try{
                    Cursor chkData = MYDB.getData(null, null);
                    if(chkData.moveToFirst()) {

                        update = MYDB.updateData(this.ProfileID , ProfileName, ProfileDesignation, ProfileMobile, ProfileEmail, ProfileCity, ProfileState, ProfileCountry, ProfileWebsite, null, null);

                        if (update == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Your Profile is Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Profile Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }else{
                        NotRegistered();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Profile Not Updated : "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btnProfileBack:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/file/3508/ORIGINAL/NONE/605209574 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F3508/ORIGINAL/NONE/605209574} }} to activity {in.mydiscover.discover_branding/in.mydiscover.discover_branding.ProfilePage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at in.mydiscover.discover_branding.ProfilePage.onActivityResult(ProfilePage.java:140)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
    ... 9 more
```

Once again I'll check in my all devices and my 99% clients devices work perfectly but shows above exceptions in my some clients devices. So please Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException. C!early marked in the log. Why did you post so much irrelevant code?

Comment: @greenapps 
Yes! I Checked.
But why data.getParcelableExtra("data"); return null value ? Because data isn't null.
You can check in log.

Comment: data may not be null but there is no such parcelable extra there. So check for null your self before executing more code. Try a different intent without crop or just different.

Comment: Also try `data.getData()` to see if it delivers a bitmap then.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for reply and I'll check with your suggestions :)

Comment: Now I checked with getdata() you can check my code of get data also provide in above as comment section. But cursor shows same error as NullPointerException and I don't know why.

Comment: You should not have fidled arountd with a cursor. And you should only use .getData() in case the other get delivered null. You still do not check if bitmab `b` is null. So you should have `if (b==null} { use getData() for an uri; if b still is null return;}`. Please adapt your code. Please tell the value of the uri. We want to know the value of `selectedPath.toString()`.